# Правильная фильтрация, обработка переменных для защиты от взломов (sql, xss)

Tags: php, безопасность

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как безопаснее всего обрабатывать переменные (числовые и строковые), чтобы защитить сайт от взломов?

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с БД пользуюсь вот такой функцией экранирования переменных, всё, что приходит из форм прогоняю через функцию:

```
function quote_smart($value)
{
    // если magic_quotes_gpc включена - используем stripslashes
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
    // Если переменная - число, то экранировать её не нужно
    // если нет - то окружем её кавычками, и экранируем
    if (!is_numeric($value)) {
        $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ModRewrite + preg_match $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: Нет, я хочу обычными функциями научиться это делать, помогите

Comment: Фильтровать POST и GET запросы. Обычные функции.

Comment: А `preg_match` волшебная что ли?^^

Comment: Не особо, но на адресной строке вполне даже!

Answer (score 0):

Всего одно правило - всё что приходит извне (`$_REQUEST, $_GET, $_POST, $COOKIE`) - от лукавого.

Над ними ни в коем случае нельзя делать `eval`.

Если работаете с базой, либо регулярными выражениями и т.д., то обязательно нужно использовать функции экранирования. (для mysql это - `mysql_real_escape_string`, для регулярных выражений `preg_quote`)

Обычные сравнения переменных - безопасны, но также стоит подумать над тем, где использовать `==`, а где `===`.

Comment: Я имею ввиду формы и так далее, Get-запросы

Comment: числа просто проверяйте на `is_numeric`, строки регулярками, перед инсертом escape_string, вообще лучше всего использовать, например со стороны БД - процедуры или со стороны php - подготовленные запросы (реализованы в PDO расширении)